# Problem with correctly running .exe file from python file

Tags: python, file, subprocess

I want to run .exe file from python file, but there is problem with reading from txt file.
Exe doesn't throw any errors, but it looks like it doesn't even open any .txt.
Additionally, .exe works well, when I enter the folder and run it manually.
How I run .exe in python:

```
subprocess.check_call(['D:\Projects\PythonProjects\PrivateGithub\MinMax\EXE\Run.exe'])
```

Should I do something 'special' to be able to read from files?

Comment: What .txt file? What do you mean by it doesn't open any .txt? What is it supposed to do? What is it doing? Why are you asking about running an exe and then asking if you should do something special to read from files? What files?

Comment: I moved .exe to another folder and now its working.
How should I exmplain you what txt file?
I use write/read to .txt in my program (written in cpp), but when I built it and run .exe from python it just doesnt worked. I mean .exe  just like ignored part of code where it should save sth to .txt file. However it worked when I have runned it just by simply clicking by mouse (not via python).
But as I said, I pull off .exe from folder and now it is working (and yes, I had all necessary files in that folder)

Comment: .exe files can run without throwing errors, if they are not coded to return error codes.  The program will execute in the current python directory, so does the exe program have a problem with that?  put your .py file and .exe file in the same directory, adjust your subprocess call to point to the correct exe path, then run your py file and see if it works that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to run the exe:

```
import os
os.startfile('D:\Projects\PythonProjects\PrivateGithub\MinMax\EXE\Run.exe')
```